# Report not showing records created by another user

Tags: custom-reports

I created a report for a custom object, but the report doesnt show all the records I want it to show. The difference between the records that show up and the ones that I don't seem to be whether or not I created them.

Role hierarchy:
System admin (the account that created the report) > Company admin (My account) > CEO (the account that created the records that don't appear in the report) > everyone else

The relevants accounts have access to all the records from this object based on the sharing rules.

Comment: Can you share more details and what exactly you want your reports to show?

Comment: For sure: I have a custom object called Cohort with the fields Year and Number of companies. I am doing a report with a stacked column chart that shows the total number of companies per year.

Answer (score 2):

Edit the report and check the filters tab. In the "Show me" filter, make sure that it says "All", not only "My".

[image]

Answer (score -1):

In the report filters, change it to "My "Object Name"" and you will see only the records that are created by you!